# Is this the proper way to count the words beacause it counts individually and also want to change the font and font color

Tags: php, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGlHF.jpg)Php advance study,Is this the proper way to count the words beacause it counts individually and also want to change the font and font color, and also i would really love to know about shortcuts

I want it to be more direct to the point code i guess, i was really new to coding world so it will be a huge help see

Comment: I don't know what to answer because I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to count the words the come from echo strlen($_POST["firstname"]); echo strlen($_POST["middlename"]);echo strlen($_POST["lastname"]); all together not individually

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all in strlen

```
strlen($_POST["firstname"].$_POST["middlename"].$_POST["lastname"]);
```